# Access closing form prevent inserting a new record

Tags: forms, ms-access, duplicates

I have a form, with a submit button. It works properly until I close it. When there is no record in table, and I add a new one, and then I close it, it duplicates the record, and copies the original one into a second one. If it is opened It doesn't copy the content, only if i close it. But only if it's the first record. If there are other records ( two or more ), it works properly. Is there any option to prevent it?

Comment: Edit question to post code. Record is committed to table when: 1) close table/query/form; or 2) move to another record; or 3) run code to save.

Comment: The proper way should be: I open the form, fill inputs, then hit submit, and it inserts the record. 
 I
BUT When I close the form, It inserts the same record again. I checked the values, in the SQL statement, and all of those names are different from input names. And it only Inserts it when theres no record in the table, and I Insert the first one.

Comment: Its not related to the code. I just removed the whole code of the form. I fill inputs without poressing submit, close it, and it inserts a new record without pressing the button. Interesting....

Comment: With a bound form and bound controls, new record (or edits to existing) committed to table when form closes. That is normal.

Comment: So I need to create a new form? it randomly changes the behaviour. Sometimes it updates the original record, sometimes It inserts a new one. Cant get the point :D

Comment: I want to limit inserting only to user.

Comment: Hard to analyze without examining code and/or db design. Not sure what you mean by 'limit inserting only to user' - user inputs data to bound controls and pass directly into table.

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First record is special with a bound form. it automatically creates a record if there is none and you add any data to any field.
Probably need to check if the form is both bound to the table and you are saving the data manually.
If you to trap and process/check the .IsDirty status of the form before a save event you can probably sort this quite easily.
As to the only one user stuff, you can set the form to read only as the default, then check the username during form-load and if it is the user with edit permissions, set edit mode or show an edit button.